# How can you calculate the normalisation factor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, normalization

when given a particle of mass $m$ in a one dimensional square potential well from $x=0-L$, How can one calculate the value of the normalisation factor $|φ\rangle = |A|(\,|1\rangle + |2\rangle\,)$ where $|A|$ is the normalisation factor? Do I have to square the normalised wave-functions for the allowed value of energy?

Comment: This seems to be a Homework type question, please review the homework policy of the site.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to use the normalization requirement
$\langle\varphi|\varphi\rangle=1$
with $|\varphi\rangle=|A|(|1\rangle+|2\rangle)$,
and see what you can conclude for $|A|$.

Hint: Make use of the orthonormalizing relations
between $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$.

Comment: if it is in a continuum, am I correct in saying I have to instead do an integral of the form  1=∫dx|ψ(x)|^2= A^2 ?

Comment: @strawhat In this case the states $|1\rangle,|2\rangle$ are already normalized. The hint that Thomas provides is already enough. No need to integrate.

Comment: Please set a better example for new users. Answering/providing solutions to off-topic homework problems gives the impression that questions like these are allowed on PSE.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I have reduced the level of details for better complying with the homework policy.

Comment: Yes, but that is for homework questions that are still on topic here. This question shouldn't have even gotten answers.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your wave function as a unit vector with two orthogonal or normal components $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ just like $\hat{i}$and$ \hat{j}$. What conditions does this impose on $|\varphi\rangle$? How would you use this to calculate $|A|$?